# How to use VP9 transcoder when streaming video in VLC Player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, transcode, vp9

I was trying to stream video with VLC using the very low latency VP9 encoder.

Both my OS codec library and VLC player (3.0.16) has been upgraded to the latest version

When I select VLC Player > Streaming > Video Format > Transcoding option, I only found VP8 codec:

[image]

How do I install and use VP9 transcoder in this case?